# Using WAMP's MySQL with Cygwin Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cygwin, rake, wamp

I'm trying to install a Rails app on a Cygwin Rails + WAMP MySQL setup, but rake trows an error :

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Of course, it's trying to connect to MySQL trought a Cygwin socket, and since there's no MySQL server running on Cygwin, it fails.

How do I get Rails to connect to WAMP's MySQL (perhaps through TCP/IP instead of a socket) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `host:127.0.0.1` to `database.yml`, forcing it to use TCP instead of a socket solved the problem.